# How to print an array elements in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing this code and in the classifykids() , I'm filling the 4 new arrays from the x array.. after that I trying to print the elements in the 4 array but It's doesn't work with me , its prints long numbers

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int *readkid(){
int * kids = new int[4];
int counter=1;
for (int i=0; i<4 ; i++ ){
    cout << "Enter the age for kid number " << counter << ":[ 1 to 10]      " << endl;
    cin >> kids[i];
    counter++;
}
return kids;
}

 void classifyKids (int * x){



int * perk = new int[20];
int * kg1 = new int[20];
int * kg2 = new int[20];
int * elementry = new int[4];


 for ( int i=0; i <21; i++){
     if ( x[i] < 3 ){
         perk[i] = x[i];
     } else if ( x[i] < 3 && x[i] > 3) {
         kg1[i] = x[i];
     } else if( x[i] > 6 && x[i] > 4){
         kg2[i] = x[i];
     } else if(x[i] > 6){
         elementry[i] = (x[i]);
     }

 }
for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
    cout << "Here is it :" << elementry[i] << endl;

    }



 int main() {

int *x;
x = readkid ();
classifyKids(x);

/*
 for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
 cout << *(x+i) << endl;
 }
 */

return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Once you have it working. It may be worth visiting http://codereview.stackexchange.com to get comments on a better style.

Comment: I see a compiler error. `x` has only 4 elements, while you are trying to access up to 21 elements!

Comment: `if (x[i] < 3 && x[i] > 3)` what kind of a condition is this??

Answer (score 0):

What could possibly be the problem? You know how to access an array element and also to take input into the array. So why can't you print?

Suppose if arr is the array you wanna print that has 4 elements, then it goes thus:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) 
    cout<< arr[i] <<" ";
```

Why it prints numbers:
You type (x+i). Both x and i are integers with some value. Maybe x has a large value which added withi produces a number that is printed. If you want to print the element at index x+i, then the coutstatement will be:

```
cout << arr[x+i] << " ";
```

where arr is the array you'd print.

Comment: but I got another problem .. If the elementry[21] got only 1 number from x[] .. its gonna print 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 .. how to let it print only the 1

Comment: Are you trying to convert the binary number stored in the array to decimal ?

Comment: No , What I mean by 1 0 0 0 0 its print the whole numbers in the array, but I only need the numbers that have value

Comment: OK so out of the numbers (either 0 or 1) you wanna print only the 1s right?